# How to pop a web browser from Silverlight OOB?

Tags: c#, silverlight, browser, silverlight-oob

I want to pop a web browser popup window, with a given url, from Silverlight.

When running *within the browser* I use `HtmlPage.Window.Invoke()` to run a javascript and its `window.open()` in the host browser. Works fine.

But when I run *out-of-browser* (OOB) this technique obviously doesn't work. So, what to do?

Silverlight 4 has this new `WebBrowser` control for use when running OOB. It works fine, but I have only been able to run it in a child window within the silverlight application boundaries.

Then there is this [hyperlink](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/216226/513215.aspx#513215) trick. Also works, but it creates a new tab in the current browser-instance. Not exactly what I want either.

Anything I have missed?

(Alternatively; is there a a way to make the hyperlink pop the url in the same browserinstance and tab every time? instead of creating new tabs.)

Bit of a long post this. Sorry about that and thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

The link you posted to creating a derived HyperlinkButton is the only one I know of.  Maybe play around with different TargetName values to see which one works like you want?  "_blank", "_new", etc... - one of them may be what you want.

The trouble is that different browsers (when set as the default browser) may do different things, so be sure to try this with IE, Firefox, on a Mac, ...